# Tracking website and mobile apps in one property

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

I have a website and two companion apps (android and iOS). The user may jump from the website to the app and vice-versa so it is important to me to know when this happens (I'm thinking about using funnels btw).
AFAIK, if I split the website and apps through multiple properties I won't be able to cross the data so I think I'll have put all tracking inside a single property. However, when I create the property, if I pick to track an app it tells me to assign the property to a Firebase App. If I pick to track a website I get a big form. Question is: can I track everything in a single property? If so, is there any guide on how to do it?

Comment: So how was your experience tracking everything in one property? I am also mulling over to do so, but still not sure.

Comment: Sorry @hhsadiq . Our client dropped the request for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a new property, the default should be website, so you get all website-related reports for your website, where probably the majority of traffic and activity is happening. This will create a default website view for all traffic coming to this tracking ID.

Then use the same tracking ID for the legacy SDKs for Android and iOS. As you'll see in the documentation, there are a lot of warnings about using Firebase for mobile app tracking. You can have 3 views for this property - for the website and for each of the mobile apps. If you want to analyze the data in one view, there'll be an issue with website tracking recording pages and mobile tracking recording screens, so you can see mobile data within website view in the Events reports. There's no option within GA interface to create a funnel of events, so you should export the data and build the funnel outside of GA.

Consider adding user ID to easily track users across platforms.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v3/